# FreeTDS for Linux 32 Bit?

Tags: linux, qt, package, 32-bit, freetds

## Freetds with Linux 32 bit

The question matters a problem with Linux 32 bit with the software freetds. On 64 Bit Linux I can install and use Freetds normally to connect with mssql server database. 
On 32 bit I can't install the aptitude search version of the package manager.
After install I get pi message of status.
While install I get errors, that show me that the datas could be load but not install.
I think it is because of the 32 bit version.
Is there a possibility to solve this problem?

```
Err: http:/de.archive.ubunti.com/ubunti raring /main freetds-common all 0.91-3 404 NOT FOUND
Err: http:/de.archive.ubunti.com/ubunti raring / libct4 i386 0.91-3 404 NOT FOUND
Failed to fetch de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetds/freetds-common 0.91-3 all.deb 404 NOT FOUND
```

and so on...

Comment: Please always write the exact error messages you're getting, otherwise it's very hard to help.

Comment: Err: http:/de.archive.ubunti.com/ubunti raring /main freetds-common all 0.91-3 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Err: http:/de.archive.ubunti.com/ubunti raring / libct4 i386 0.91-3 404 NOT FOUND

Comment: Failed to fetch http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/f/freetds/freetds-common 0.91-3 all.deb 404 NOT FOUND